# How do you use redefine a method and still use the original unmodified inherited method in the method?

Tags: python, class, methods, python-3.x

That question was worded poorly but I couldn't think of a better way to put it. This is also probably an easy question but it's hard to describe properly to search for it. I'm coding in python for the record.

I'm trying create a new class that inherits the list type. It's supposed to effectively be a list of another class I defined where one of the variables of that class is an int. When the list is sorted I want it to sort based on those ints. When I'm redefining sort on the class however how I make it use the original sort from list type.

Comment: The question still seems ambiguous. Try to whittle it down to one sentence (in bold.) That will make it easier for us to answer your question.

Comment: If you're just asking "how to I call the method of the same name in my superclass`, see [`super`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just asking "how do I call my superclass's `sort` method from my `sort` method, that's done using [super](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super).

For example, if you just want to make the `key` in `sort` default to `int` in Python 2.7:

```
class MyList(list):
    def sort(self, cmp=None, key=None, reverse=None):
        if cmp is None and key is None:
            key = int
        return super(MyList, self).sort(cmp, key, reverse)
```

In 3.3, it's even simpler with magic `super` (and also, there's no `cmp` parameter to `sort`):

```
class MyList(list):
    def sort(self, key=None, reverse=None):
        if key is None:
            key = int
        return super().sort(key, reverse)
```

---

If you're asking how to monkeypatch in a method that calls the old method, that's a bit trickier… but the key is that functions and methods are first-class values, so you can save them in variables, attributes, etc.

In 2.7:

```
old_sort = MyList.sort
def new_sort(self, cmp=None, key=None, reverse=None):
    if cmp is None and key is None:
        key = int
    return old_sort(self, cmp, key, reverse)
MyList.sort = types.UnboundMethodType(new_sort, None, MyList)
```

Again, 3.3 is simpler, this time because unbound methods are the same thing as functions:

```
old_sort = MyList.sort
def new_sort(self, key=None, reverse=None):
    if key is None:
        key = int
    return old_sort(self, key, reverse)
MyList.sort = new_sort
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know exactly what parent class has the overridden method you want to invoke (I'm assuming in this case it's `list` and `sort`, respectively), you can invoke the parent class's method in the child class like so:

```
def sort(self, ...):
    ...
    list.sort(self, ...)
    ...
```